# Temporarily reduce physical RAM size in Redhat 5 for testing

Tags: rhel

How to reduce the physical RAM size in RHEL 5.7?

I would like to reduce the memory for testing

Answer (score 2):

Use `mem=size` [kernel parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt). This will force the kernel to use only that much memory. That is, if you want to test your system/software to run with less memory.

If it is RAM testing you are talking about, then `memtester(8)` will `mlock(3)` the memory being tested, thus effectively removing it from system usage (but you should test your RAM with specialised software running without OS, such as [memtest+](http://www.memtest.org/) anyway, if you can afford the downtime).

Answer (score -2):

You could stop using your swapfile, and occupy memory with other programs.

```
swapoff -a
```

For further information read `man swapon` or `man swapoff`

Or setup a Virtual Machine with less RAM configured. This is a bit more work, but probably useful in the long term, but does mean you need a CPU that supports Virtual machines.

Comment: Disabling swap space won't reduce your physical RAM.

Comment: You should not play with swap. It's here for a reason, and a good one. Also, memory could be compacted (even if the feature shouldn't be available in redhat 5) which will lead to a memory usage under what we would like. Another valid option would to use "crashkernel" boot option to reserve memory, unavailable for the running kernel.

Comment: @Vinz Physically removing your RAM is the only way to reduce your physical RAM, OP wants to test and requires a temporary solution.

Comment: @AdrienM. There is no reason not to turn off swap (unless you are very tight on memory), I do not even install swap on servers with a lot of RAM (since for the swap to have any reason its size should be comparable with RAM and if your server needs swapping out several GB's, then you are in troubles anyway). Swap is very important in just one way: as a place to store the RAM when hibernating.

Comment: @Adrien M, why shouldn't he remove swap, worst thing that can happen is he runs out of RAM, which is what he wants to test? I'm not suggesting that this is standard practice for your critical server running production code. Compaction is about contiguising memory fragments, changing crashkernel boot parameters requires a reboot, so not quite as convenient. I gave a quick easy solution. A better which requires more work, would be to configure a VM with less memory. Why the down votes?

Comment: @XTian : Removing physical RAM is not the only way. You can use the `mem=size` kernel's argument to limit it. Removing the swap won't reduce the physical RAM available.

Comment: @Vinz Disabling swap reduces the available (virtual) memory available and allows memory out conditions to be tested earlier. Reducing amount of actual RAM used (mem=size), forces the kernel to use the swap earlier but doesn't stop the kernel using it.

Comment: Ok so it was about memory "compression" not "compaction". My bad. About the parameter ``mem=`` it's why I flagged original question : duplicate of question done 3 years ago. For swap, the subject is already covered multiple times on the net. To keep it simple : effective caching. Even with TB of RAM.